# SharePoint 2010 basic search on a sub-site wont return results

Tags: search-results

I added a Basic Search site on a subsite and scope to contextual search. for some reason it does not return result. However, I crawl logs show all the items that it's being crawling for that subsite and libraries.

If I do advance search then it brings the result. I can see the documents that are in the subsite (well after I go through refinement)

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Do I have to pass the url of the sub-site to the "Search Core Results" webpart?

Comment: I just noticed in the url that "This Site" includes the search site but should have been just the parent site. For example cs=This Site&u=http://portal/ParentSite/SubSite/Search but it should be cs=This Site&u=http://portal/ParentSite/SubSite. Is there a way to force change this?

Comment: I end up creating a search scope and now it's fine. Thanks